# what is the connection string to connect sql server with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I need what are all the connection string wanted to connect database server (SQL Server 2005)
example server name, password, username like wise, I don't know how to connect ASP.NET with SQL Server 2005 database - give me a perfect connection string to connect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#p1